# Could light be considered considered a type of gas?

Tags: speed-of-light

I propose this question largely due to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcqZHYo7ONs) (see 4:19) and how it describes light going through polarized lenses. The effect described there could be explained if you consider light to function like a gas, in that it fills whatever space it is in.

At first glance you might think that there is no "container" therefore it is not filling a space. However, consider the light that around lenses as a thicker substance. The light being filtered would only be allowed to pass through at a certain angle, and therefor would have overall less total energy. In theory, the light around the lens is acting as a wall, while the filtered light expands to fill the void. In essence, this could be compared to how cavitation works on boat propellers.

**My Question:** Are there any studies that could disprove or prove this theory?

Comment: This is not a theory. A physical theory is expressed in predictive mathematical formulas. Without the math the best you can hope for is a new interpretation of the existing theory. However, your idea does not qualify, because you assume that the light outside the lens interacts with the light inside the lens. This is incorrect, because, according to the superposition principle, light waves do not interact with each other.

Comment: There is a notion of [photon gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas), but it is about something entirely different. We do not evaluate personal theories here.